Querying Grafana for traces with tempo
I am trying to query and graph the data from the span attributes in traces via Tempo.
I can find all the traces I require, but I am having trouble getting the data for the span attributes into graphs.
I want to create a time series graph of when the merchant.configuration.cache.refreshed = true by the merchant. See trace example below.
Thanks for any help in advance

